# Outlook 2016 macro to edit received email

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to be able to add notes to received emails so that I can keep track of work I've done or need to do. We just switched from Lotus Notes to Office365 and after doing some research I've figured out how to edit a received email. You have to open the email then go to Actions --> Edit Message.

Those aren't too many steps but a keyboard shortcut or button would make it much faster.

I did some research and learned a bit about Macros. I don't know how to write VB and was wondering if anyone could give me a hand writing it.

These are the steps I would need:

1. Open the currently selected email
2. Make it editable

As a bonus I would like change the font color to red. It just delineates text I've added versus the original email.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this: [VBA macro to open Outlook 2016 message as “Editable”](https://superuser.com/questions/1338280/vba-macro-to-open-outlook-2016-message-as-editable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @victor, your comment led me to the right place.

This is what I used in case anyone else would like to know:

```
Sub OpenForEditing()
    ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Display
    ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "EditMessage"
End Sub
```