# Save mail with WordEditor as pdf with header

Tags: vba, email, pdf, outlook

I would like to save a mail body and header just as if it were printed by Outlook or PDFCreator. The sender, cc, bcc , time, to, subject are data that must be in the pdf.

Using this post and others: [Print mail item as pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402806/print-mail-item-as-pdf)

I coded this macro that:

- takes the selected mails in Outlook
- makes a new folder in hardcoded folder
- prints with the WordEditor the mail body as PDF

The WordEditor object doesn't save the HEADER of the mailItem. It is important for me to have the information of who sent it, when, the e-mail address, Subject etc.

I want to know how to add the header from the WordEditor object.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub mail_to_pdf_sof()
    Dim outApp As Object, objOutlook As Object, objFolder As Object, myItems As Object, myItem As Object, coll As Object, Sel As Object, objInspector As Object, objDoc As Object
    Dim psName As String, pdfName As String, strFolderpath As String, Path As String, time_record As String, FileName As String
    Dim rol As Integer, indice As Integer, i As Integer
    
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objOutlook = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' PATH TO SAVE PDFs
    Path = "F:\"
    Path = Path & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " - Mail to PDF" & "\"
    
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir Path
    On Error GoTo 0
 
    ' GET MAILS SELECTED IN OUTLOOK FOR THE CONVERSION AND SAVE TO PDF
    Set coll = New VBA.Collection

    If TypeOf Application.ActiveWindow Is Outlook.Inspector Then
        coll.Add Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Else
        Set Sel = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    
        For i = 1 To Sel.Count
            coll.Add Sel(i)
        Next
    End If

    ' SET COUNTERS
    rol = 1
    indice = 1
    time_record = Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmm")

    ' SAVE EACH MAIL AS PDF BUT WITHOUT THE HEADER 
    For Each myItem In coll
        
        ' ELIMINATES CHARACTER THAT ARE NOT ALLOWD AND SET A MAX TO FILE NAME LENGTH
        FileName = myItem.SenderName & " - " & myItem.Subject
        FileName = Replace(FileName, ":", "")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, "|", "-")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, "/", "-")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, "\", "-")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, "\\", "-")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, Chr(34), "")

        If Len(FileName) > 90 Then
            FileName = Left(FileName, 90)
        End If
        
        ' SAVE AS PDF
        Set objInspector = myItem.GetInspector
        Set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
        objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat Path & time_record & " - " & rol & " - " & "Mail - " & FileName & ".pdf", 17
        Set objInspector = Nothing
        Set objDoc = Nothing

        rol = rol + 1
        indice = indice + 1
    
    Next myItem

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is *Option Explicit*? Also read Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
**https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: I"m a begginer at coding. It is VBA, it is easly understandable. Copy and paste it and it works. If anyone knew the subject that i"m asking for, he or she certainly knows the problem i"m exposing, because it  is really common. Option Explicit dont change anything to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get sender, cc, time, to, subject, **not bcc**, by saving a forwarded version.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub mail_to_pdf_sof()
    
    Dim Path As String
    
    Dim coll As VBA.Collection
    Dim Sel As Selection
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rol As Long
    Dim time_record As String
    
    Dim myItem As Object
    
    Dim FileName As String
    
    Dim objInspector As Inspector
    Dim objDoc As Object
        
    ' PATH TO SAVE PDFs
    Path = "F:\"
    
    Path = Path & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " - Mail to PDF" & "\"
    
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir Path
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' GET MAILS SELECTED IN OUTLOOK FOR THE CONVERSION AND SAVE TO PDF
    Set coll = New VBA.Collection
    
    If TypeOf ActiveWindow Is Inspector Then
        coll.add Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem
        
    Else
        Set Sel = ActiveExplorer.Selection
        For i = 1 To Sel.count
            coll.add Sel(i)
        Next
        
    End If
    
    ' SET COUNTERS
    rol = 1
    time_record = Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmm")
    
    ' SAVE EACH MAIL WITH THE HEADER
    For Each myItem In coll
        
        ' ELIMINATES CHARACTER THAT ARE NOT ALLOWD AND SET A MAX TO FILE NAME LENGTH
        FileName = myItem.SenderName & " - " & myItem.Subject
        FileName = Replace(FileName, ":", "")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, "|", "-")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, "/", "-")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, "\", "-")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, "\\", "-")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, Chr(34), "")
        
        If Len(FileName) > 90 Then
            FileName = Left(FileName, 90)
        End If
        
        'Debug.Print FileName
        
        If myItem.Class = olMail Then
            
            Set myItem = myItem.Forward    ' <----
            
            ' SAVE AS PDF
            Set objInspector = myItem.GetInspector
            Set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
            
            objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat Path & time_record & " - " & rol & " - " & _
              "Mail - " & FileName & ".pdf", 17
              
            myItem.Close olDiscard

            Set objInspector = Nothing
            Set objDoc = Nothing
            
            rol = rol + 1
            
        End If
        
    Next myItem
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, however, the attachment list is lost. You don't know if the mail had or not attachament. But it is good solution anyway. Thanks!

Comment: As the forward item is editable, I can add the attachment list and other things. Thank you again! Great help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to extract the internet header from the mail in question. It only took a simple google search *outlook vba header information*

```
Option Explicit
Const DRIVE = "F:\"
Const ROOTPATH = "Mail\"

Sub mail_to_pdf_sof()
    Dim outApp As Object, objOutlook As Object, objFolder As Object, myItems As Object, myItem As Object, coll As Object, Sel As Object, objInspector As Object, objDoc As Object
    Dim psName As String, pdfName As String, strFolderpath As String, Path As String, time_record As String, FileName As String
    Dim rol As Integer, indice As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim Header As String '*** The header here
    
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objOutlook = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' PATH TO SAVE PDFs
    
    Path = DRIVE & ROOTPATH
    Path = Path & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " - Mail to PDF" & "\"
    
    On Error Resume Next
     MkDir Path
    On Error GoTo -1 ' *** Reset error handling
 
    ' GET MAILS SELECTED IN OUTLOOK FOR THE CONVERSION AND SAVE TO PDF

    Set coll = New VBA.Collection

    If TypeOf Application.ActiveWindow Is Outlook.Inspector Then
        coll.Add Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Else
        Set Sel = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    
        For i = 1 To Sel.Count
            coll.Add Sel(i)
        Next

    End If

    ' SET COUNTERS
    
    rol = 1
    indice = 1
    time_record = Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmm")

    ' SAVE EACH MAIL AS PDF BUT WITHOUT THE HEADER
    
    For Each myItem In coll
        
        ' ELIMINATES CHARACTER THAT ARE NOT ALLOWD AND SET A MAX TO FILE NAME LENGTH
        
        FileName = myItem.SenderName & " - " & myItem.subject
        FileName = Replace(FileName, ":", "")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, "|", "-")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, "/", "-")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, "\", "-")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, "\\", "-")
        FileName = Replace(FileName, Chr(34), "")

        If Len(FileName) > 90 Then
        FileName = Left(FileName, 90)
        End If
      
        '*
        '* Get the header for this mail into the string Header
        '* Do whatever you want with it
        '* (merge it with the mail or save as a separate file)
        '*
        Header = GetInetHeaders(myItem)
        
        ' SAVE AS PDF
        
        Set objInspector = myItem.GetInspector
        Set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
        objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat Path & time_record & " - " & rol & " - " & "Mail - " & FileName & ".pdf", 17
        Set objInspector = Nothing
        Set objDoc = Nothing

        rol = rol + 1
        indice = indice + 1
    
  Next myItem

End Sub
'*********************************************************************************
'* Get the header from the mailitem
'* https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/outlooks-internet-headers
'*
Function GetInetHeaders(olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem) As String
    ' Purpose: Returns the internet headers of a message.'
    ' Written: 4/28/2009'
    ' Author:  BlueDevilFan'
    ' //techniclee.wordpress.com/
    ' Outlook: 2007'
    Const PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"
    Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Set olkPA = olkMsg.PropertyAccessor
    GetInetHeaders = olkPA.GetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS)
    Set olkPA = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thank  you very much, Sture. But the problem is not to get the header data (mailItem.senderName, etc is another option) instead, as the title and one of my erased comment says, It is to include it in the pdf before the body mail, just as if you print it from outlook. It is not to simple to merge them as the mail body is a read only object. Creating a new mail and copying the original one to have the possibility of editing is not to simple either. The HTMLBody usually has embedded images and copying them to a new mail is not to easy as they must be added as attachment one by one.

Comment: This is not a coding service where you state your requirements and get back ready-to-run debugged code. 
You need to put in some efforts yourself. Show us what you have tried this far.
Also read Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
**https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: ... Must add, that it is necessary to temporarly  save the attachment to get a folder route to pass it to the add method... it is a mess

Comment: What Ive tryed Ive tryed it after posting.

Comment: You never mentioned the existence of attachments in your question. How will they appear in the PDF file?

Comment: Outlook save the body html embedded images as attachments. There are not "real" attachments in my question. The saveAs method of the mailItem object saves them embedded in the pdf as they appears in the original mail. But if the solution to add the header in the pdf implies creating a new mail object to allow editing (with the range.insertBefore method), embedded images that are attached in the original mail must be copy or reattached in that New mail. You cant do "newmail.attachments = originalmail.attachments"

Comment: My notion of your approach is that you want to do everything in one go. Professional programmers divide bigger problems into smaller tasks (subroutines). For each email I'd: 1. Create a folder for this email, it's header and possible attachments. 2. Save the email as text. 3. Save the header as text. 4. Save possibly attachments. 
When all emails are processed I'd start  code that combine the files in each folder and save the lot of that folder as a PDF file.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Can be the combining pdf routine be run from vba? The point of this macro is to save an email as pdf with just one button.

Comment: Everything is possible. Just work on writing the code step by step and stop assuming it's just a couple of lines or that it can all be solved at once. Babysteps if you like ....
Regarding the final step of making a PDF, you can fire up Word from inside Outlook's VBA and then have access to all Word features. But, then again, baby steps ...

Comment: @David_Rowie Re: "as the mail body is a read only object.". You can edit the mail body. In VBA see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347992/outlook-2016-macro-to-edit-received-email

Answer (score 0):

David Rowie wrote: *Option Explicit dont change anything to my question*

Without Option Explicit your code compiles.
However with Option explicit you get a compile error:

[image: Path is not defined]

Please add Option Explicit and correct all compile errors first of all.

Comment: Consider deleting this as it is not an answer.

Comment: Only way to attach a picture to show that Option Explicit is crucial to have. Part of the solution.